# Exchange SDK Streaming API: Fetch new mail content and subject

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I need a quick help. How can I use Exchange Streaming API to intercept New Mail Arrival Event every time and fetch it content.

[This](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-ews-streaming-notifications-in.html) article talks about PowerSHell and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/12/22/working-with-streaming-notifications-by-using-the-ews-managed-api.aspx) talks about Console APP. How do I automate it? One way is Windows Service but is there any other and easy way??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Need some Kind of host which receives the notifications. Whether this is a console application or a Windows Service is up to you.